# Mpeg Dash - fragmentation and segmentation

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, packager, shaka

I am trying to implement Mpeg DASH streaming using shaka packager.
To generate segments of duration 5 seconds each, **--segment_duration** param helps me achieve this.

https://google.github.io/shaka-packager/html/documentation.html#chunking-options

I could see how a fragmented video is represented from the following link

[What exactly is Fragmented mp4(fMP4)? How is it different from normal mp4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4)

1. What is the purpose of fragmentation?
2. Does the packager automatically create fragments when segmented?
3. Does each segment have moof+mdat as represented above?
4. What are subsegments?
5. What happens if **--segment_duration** and **--fragment_duration** is set to the same value?
6. What is the purpose of --min-buffer-time?

Comment: I am also looking for similar answers. Were you able to get answers for these?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Segments are a property of DASH. A segment is the minimal download unit.

Fragments are a property of fragmented MP4 files. Typically a fragment consists of moof + mdat.

A fragmented MP4 is usually created as ftyp moov | moof mdat | moof mdat | ... | moof mdat |.

A regular MP4 is ftyp moov mdat or ftyp mdat moov.

A fragmented MP4 is more reliable since individual fragments can be independently decoded. A long lasting recorder is a good use case. In case of a power loss an incomplete fragmented MP4 is stil useful.

In DASH I would align fragments and segments. You probably could have multiple fragments per segments.