# What options are there for low latency video streaming in the iOS webview?

Tags: webview, html5-video, mobile-safari

I need a to display a low latency (less than 5 seconds) video stream in my HTML5 app. The app is running in a webkit webview on iOS (not mobile Safari). I have explored and eliminated the below options.

Are there any options out there for displaying a low latency video stream in a webview?

**WebRTC:**
JS API not implemented in webview (although now supported in mobile safari)

**RTMP:** 
Flash players not supported in webview

**RTSP:** 
Not supported on iOS even when tunneled through websockets (Streamedian).

**HLS and/or DASH:** 
Latency is too high

Comment: Beware: WebRTC is supported in Webviews. getUserMedia, i.e. access to camera is not.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Is RTCPeerConnection implemented in the webview?

Comment: If only stupid apple would support media source extensions in iphone safari, this would be easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186634/sending-periodic-metadata-in-fragmented-live-mp4-stream

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a project that allows low latency HLS with any normal player all the way back in 2016 for that specific reason - no support for this from at that point any of the native players.

In HLS is actually quite easy to go quite low on latency, but it does require a server working in a bit different way than a normal file server - it should present the chunks on the playlist before they appear and wait until they show up when they're requested.

I have decided to open source my efforts so you can try this here: [github.com:signicode/ahead-server](https://github.com/signicode/ahead-server).

There are things to be done, so all the help is welcome.