# "Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats" on popular Big Buck Bunny mp4 video

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, mime-types, mp4

I'm trying to use [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) to play my video:

```
const videoTag = document.getElementById('theVideoId');
const mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="' + audioCodec + ', ' + videoCodec + '"';

if (!('MediaSource' in window) || !MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
    console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}

const mediaSource = new MediaSource();

videoTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
videoTag.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (_) {
        console.log(this.readyState); // open
        resolve();
    });
});

const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

//....

sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(chunk));
```

With the above code some videos play just fine. Others, give a warning:

```
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2 avc1.4d400c", video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2 avc1.4d400c"
```

What is interesting is that my `if` statement in the code above

```
if (!('MediaSource' in window) || !MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
```

acts like the `mimeCodec` source is supported because it does not throw the `Unsupported MIME type or codec` error. I'm also skeptial of the `Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats` error because the exact same video plays on my Google Photos account so I know my browser does support it.

How can I solve it? Is there a way to add in a "decoder" for `codec` types not natively supported or can I re-format the video into a more common supported `codec` type? The video is one of the common [Big Buck Bunny mp4](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) videos, so I'm also wondering if my code has something missing since that video seems widely supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MediaSource extension only supports [fragmented mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4), the file hosted by w3school is not fragmented.

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE#Checking_Fragmentation) for ways to reencode it properly.