# FireFox Video throws warning but video actually works?

Tags: firefox, video, ffmpeg, mp4

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- FF: 85.0.1
- Error/warning: Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/mp4, video/mp4

Same error for video/ogg

Here are my questions: 1) **The video still plays fine once loaded, and there is no error in Chrome or Chromium.** Why does the video work fine after loading but throws the error on load? 2) Is there anything that can be done without re-encoding over 2 gigs of video?

**Context:** this is an old no-profit site that used Flash for video and we really don't want to throw a lot of time at, but there are gigs of videos. I converted all .flv files and .mpg files to .mp4 using the most simple of ffmpeg commands, examples:

```
ffmpeg -i video-source.flv video-source.mp4
ffmpeg -i video-source.mpg video-source.mp4
ffmpeg -i video-source.mpg video-source.ogg
```

As I watched the ffmpeg output, it looked to me like the codec was H264 (at least, I think that is what I am seeing, not a video expert.)

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> theora (libtheora))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
```

Server response in a direct request to the mp4 files is

```
Content-Type
    video/mp4
```

I have seen the documentation and posts on [fragmented mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334051/cannot-play-media-no-decoders-for-requested-formats-on-popular-big-buck-bunny) and if re-encoding is the only option, we're probably going to abandon as it does play once loaded.

Code is simplistic, using an html5 doctype:

```
  <video id=some-container-id" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="/images/video/mp4/video-source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="/images/video/ogg/video-source.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Is the only option here to pander to FireFox and re-encode everything since as mentioned, it plays fine once loaded and throws no error in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore the warning. It's wrong and fixed in [Firefox 86](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1674315).