# HTML5 video tag not working on iOS's browser (iPhone)

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, video, browser

## Context

I am trying to play a video in edge browser.
The project framework is
`.NET 6 MVC` and `VUE` for client side
`.NET 6 WebApi` for server side

the client's Vue component will send request with range header (1MB) to request fragmented MP4, and use [media Source extension(MSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) to append arrayBuffer to the blobUrl that point to `video.src`.

like this

```js
var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
```

This works fine in window's EDGE, **BUT** didn't work on **iPhone** (tested by `iPhone SE`'s edge browser)
the video tag didn't work, it only show a blank page.
image from `iPhone SE` (EDGE Version 100.0.1185.50)
[image]

Works fine on window's EDGE Version 100.0.1185.50
image from `window 10`
[image]

## Tried Solution

I had tried add `playsinline` prop to video tag and other solutions in  [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad), but still didn't work.

## Code Snippet

The Vue Component's method is as bellow:

```js
    /*
         * check the videoId is equal to course or not.
         * if not, fetch new video stream, and create blob url to this.videoUrl
         */
        async displayVideo() {
          if (this.videoId != this.course) {
            //common.loader.show("#255AC4", 1.5, "Loading...");
            this.videoId = this.course;
    
            let video = document.querySelector("video");
            let assetURL = FrontEndUrl + `/Stream/${this.videoId}`;
            let mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
            let sourceBuffer;
            let chunkSize;
            let contentRange;
            let loop;
            let index;
    
            const token = common.cookieManager.getCookieValue(`signin`);
    
            if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
              let mediaSource = new MediaSource;
              mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
              video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
            } else {
              console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
            }
    
            function sourceOpen() {
              // chunkSize set to 1MB
              chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
    
              // index set to 1 because the fetchNextSegment start from second fragment
              index = 1;
    
              // 取出 mediaSource 並且把sourceBuffer加上 updateend event
              let mediaSoruce = this;
              sourceBuffer = mediaSoruce.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
              sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", fetchNextSegment);
    
              fetchArrayBuffer(assetURL, chunkSize * 0, appendBuffer);
    
              //  這裡會報一個 DOM interact 的 錯誤
              //video.play();
            }
    
            function fetchNextSegment() {
              if (index > loop) {
                sourceBuffer.removeEventListener("updateend", fetchNextSegment);
                return;
              }
    
              fetchArrayBuffer(assetURL, chunkSize * index, appendBuffer);
    
              index++;
            }
    
            function fetchArrayBuffer(url, range, appendBuffer) {
              fetch(url, {
                headers: {
                  "Range": `bytes=${range}-`,
                  "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                }
              })
                .then(response => {
                  if (!loop) {
                    contentRange = response.headers.get("x-content-range-total");
                    loop = Math.floor(contentRange / chunkSize);
                  }
    
                  return response.arrayBuffer();
                })
                .then(data => { appendBuffer(data) });
            }
    
            function appendBuffer(videoChunk) {
              if (videoChunk) {
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(videoChunk);
              }
            }
    
            //  這是原本舊的方式，此方式無法附上 JWT token
            // this.videoUrl = await this.fetchVideoStream(this.videoId); //FrontEndUrl + `/Stream/${this.videoId}`;
    
            //common.loader.close();
          }
        },
```

And My Vue's template

```html
    <p-card>
              <template #header>
              </template>
              <template #title>
                  <h2>課程名: {{courseName}}</h2>
              </template>
              <template #subtitle>
              </template>
              <template #content>
              <video id="video" style="width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden;" :key="videoUrl" v-on:loadeddata="setCurrentTime" v-on:playing="playing" v-on:pause="pause" controls autoplay playsinline>
              </video>
              </template>
              <template #footer>
              版權所有．轉載必究
              </template>
              </p-card>
```

I also had logs in machine, but the logs was normal.

Does anyone know why it can's work on the iOS's EDGE? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary

After checked at [Can I use MSE](https://caniuse.com/?search=MSE), found the reason is the **IOS of iPhone does not support MSE** (Media Source Extension). So the MSE didn't work.

an image from [Can I use MSE](https://caniuse.com/?search=MSE)
[image]

#### Solution

The iPhone's iOS support [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) originally ([apple dev docs](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/)), so you need to convert the MP4 to **HLS** format.(can use [bento4 HLS](https://www.bento4.com/developers/hls/))
 MP4 format must be [fMP4 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4)

After converted, the HLS format output directory will look like this
[image]

The filename extension should be `.m3u8`, and the `master.m3u8` is a doument that describe the video's all information.

Then let the video tag's src attribute point to the HLS resource's URL(`master.m3u8`).
like this sample code

```js
<video src="https://XXX/master.m3u8">
</video>
```

Also can use [the videoJS library](https://videojs.com/), the srcObject's type is `"application/x-mpegURL"`

```js
   var player = videojs("videoId");
   if (this.iOS()) {
        // ⚠ 驗證會失敗 還不清楚原因，有確定後端 驗證 是正常的
        //const token = common.cookieManager.getCookieValue(`signin`);
        url = FrontEndUrl + `/Media/Video/${this.videoId}/master.m3u8`;
        srcObject = { src: url, type: "application/x-mpegURL" }
      }

      try {
        player.src(srcObject);
        player.play();
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
        console.log(e);
      }
```

a simple HLS demo on [github page](https://github.com/s780609/HLSDemo)
But this demo use the [`hls.js`](https://nochev.github.io/hls.js/docs/html/) not [`video.js`](https://videojs.com/)

```html
<iframe width="auto" src="https://s780609.github.io/hlsJsDemo/">
</iframe>
```

#### Reference of [bento4](https://www.bento4.com/)

Convert to HLS format command example
 -f: force to replace the old file
     -o: output directory

```bash
mp4hls -f -o [output directory] [source mp4 file]
```