# Output multi-file fragmented MP4 from GStreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, video-encoding

GStreamer can output a single-file [fragmented MP4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4), using a pipeline like this:

```
❯ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=../test.ts ! decodebin ! x264enc ! ismlmux fragment-duration=6000 faststart=1 ! filesink location=fragmented.mp4
```

Using Bento4, we can confirm that the file contains interleaved `moof` and `mdat` atoms (I'm filtering for top-level atoms only since the full output is very long):

```
❯ mp4dump fragmented.mp4 | egrep '^[^ ]'
[ftyp] size=8+16
[moov] size=8+833
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+538271
[moof] size=8+2964
[mdat] size=8+296190
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+484946
[moof] size=8+2964
[mdat] size=8+305615
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+482052
[moof] size=8+2964
[mdat] size=8+298039
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+478313
[moof] size=8+2964
[mdat] size=8+294548
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+483575
[moof] size=8+2964
[mdat] size=8+303894
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+483527
[moof] size=8+2964
[mdat] size=8+316919
```

Using Bento4, we can also split the file into separate files -- `init.mp4` containing the initial metadata, and a file for each `moof`+`mdat` pair.

```
❯ mp4split fragmented.mp4
❯ ls
fragmented.mp4  segment-1.0001.m4s  segment-1.0003.m4s  segment-1.0005.m4s  segment-1.0007.m4s  segment-1.0009.m4s  segment-1.0011.m4s
init.mp4        segment-1.0002.m4s  segment-1.0004.m4s  segment-1.0006.m4s  segment-1.0008.m4s  segment-1.0010.m4s  segment-1.0012.m4s
❯ mp4dump init.mp4 | egrep '^[^ ]'
[ftyp] size=8+16
[moov] size=8+833
[udta] size=8+53
[mvex] size=8+52
❯ mp4dump segment-1.0001.m4s | egrep '^[^ ]'
[moof] size=8+5112
[mdat] size=8+538271
```

However, `mp4split` needs the full file first in order to split it, and I need to support live streaming, meaning that this approach is infeasible. **Is there a way to output the fMP4 split into multiple files directly from GStreamer?**

I tried [splitmuxsink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/splitmuxsink.html), but it seems to produce individually playable independent MP4 files, not fragments. I also tried using [multifilesink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/multifilesink.html) to save the fragmented MP4, but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell it to split the file at specific atoms.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution in the end?

Comment: @Urmzd Sadly, no. I'm no longer on that project, so I don't know if/how it was solved in the end.

Answer (score 0):

there're several properties you can set for mp4mux/qtmux/matroskamux etc. like:

splitmuxsink **muxer='mp4mux faststart=true streamable=true fragment-duration=1000 trak-timescale=1000 movie-timescale=1000 presentation-time=true'** max-size-time=1000000000 location=file%02d.mp4

Comment: This method won't write a separate init.mp4 file, though -- as I described in the question, splitmuxsink produces individual full mp4 files for each time segment, not mp4 fragments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).